# Check the irreducibility of the polynomial over $\mathbb Z$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

- $f_1(x) = x^5 + 5x^2 + 1$
- $f_2(x) = x^4 - x^3 + 14 x^2 + 5x + 16$

Use the result if $p(x)$ is a monic polynomial with integer coefficient and $p(d) \neq 0$ for all integer $d$ dividing the constant term of $p(x)$ , then $p(x)$ has no root in $\mathbb Q$

Thus both $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ have no root in $\mathbb Z$. Also we can not apply Eisentein  Criterion. Give me any idea how to show that $f_i's$ are irreducible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both polynomials are irreducible.

Hint for $f_1$: Use reduction modulo $2$ and that $x^2+x+1$ is the only irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ of degree $2$.

Hint for $f_2$: Use reduction modulo $5$. (Perhaps there is something more elegant.)

Comment: it should be $ x^5 +x^2 +1$. in $\mathbb F_2 [x]$. how can you say that it is irreducible in $\mathbb F_2$

Comment: No, I mean $x^2+x+1$, which is clearly irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$, in fact the only irreducible polynomial of degree $2$. You check that $x^2+x+1$ does not divide $x^5+x^2+1$, and that $x^5+x^2+1$ has no roots. Hence, $x^5+x^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$.